# Semitransparent ActionBar in AppCompat

Tags: android, alpha, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

I want to use a semitransparent actionbar.
`android:minSdkVersion is "9"`

I have tried below code

```
<style name="myActionBarTheme" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
   <item name="android:background">#FF4444</item>
   <item name="android:alpha">1.0</item>
</style>
```

It is showing error : `android:alpha requires API level 11 (current min is 9)`

Comment: Try this one `<item name="android:background">#90FF4444</item>`

Comment: Agreed, just define the alpha in the color itself.

Comment: It show error while running : java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity